# Why Stokes theorem gives negative answer here?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I wanted to verify stokes theorem for $\int \int_Scurl F.dS$ with $F=[-y,x,-xyz]$ with S is surface of cone of equation with $z^2=x^2+y^2$ with is $0\leq z\leq 11$.

Parameterisation of S is given by

$r:[0,2\pi] \times [0,11]\to \mathbb R^3$

$r(u,v)=(v\cos(u),v\sin(u),v)$

$r_u=\left(-v\sin(u),v\cos(u),0\right)$
$r_v=(\cos(u),\sin(u),1)$
$r_u\times r_v=(v\cos(u),v\sin(u),-v)$

$\int \int_S(\bigtriangledown \times F).dS=\int\int_S(\bigtriangledown \times F).n ds$

$=\int\int_S (\bigtriangledown \times F).\frac{r_u\times r_v}{||r_u\times r_v||}||r_u\times r_v||dA$

$=\int\int_S (\bigtriangledown \times F)(r).(r_u\times r_v)dA$
$
=\int_0^{11}\int_0^{2\pi} (-v^2\cos(u),v^2\sin(u),2).(v\cos(u),v\sin(u),-v)dudv$

$=\int_0^{11}\int_0^{2\pi}(-v^3\cos^2(u)+v^3\sin^2(u)-2v)dudv
$
$=\int_0^{11}0-4\pi v dv$
$=-2\pi v^2|_0^{11}$
$=-242\pi$

Now we will use stokes theorem ,

$F=[-y,x,-xyz]$, $curl(F)=\bigtriangledown \times F=[-xz,yz,2]$

$S=\{(x,y,z)|z^2=x^2+y^2, 0\leq z\leq 11\}$

$\gamma$ is circle with radius 11 and centered at (0,0,11)    as z=11.
So parameterization of $ \gamma : r(t)=(11\cos(t),11\sin(t),11)$

$ 0\leq t\leq 2\pi$
$\int_{\gamma} F.dr=\int_0^{2\pi}F(r(t)).r'(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(-11\sin(t),11\cos(t),-11^3\sin(t)\cos(t)).(-11\sin(t),11\cos(t),0)dt$
$=\int_0^{2\pi}121.(1)dt=242\pi.$

Why answer is negative ? Please help me

Comment: Have you checked your orientation?

Comment: Just some recommendations: for the gradient operator, use $\nabla$ (```\nabla```). For "curl", use $\operatorname{curl}$ (```\operatorname{curl}```). For the dot product, use $\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ (```\boldsymbol{\cdot}```). Also it's Stokes's theorem, not "stokes" theorem.